# Velocity(factor) of different cable types - Collision domain

Tags: layer1, cable

I need to calculate the max length of a collision domain.
There is this [formula.](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/b7557843f69e1ac3177238cc37e5e18b545c80f4)

In short: `maxLength = (c * velocityFactor * 512 Bit)/(vBit)`

- c = speed of light
- velocity factor = ?
- vBit = bit transfer speed

Well I know that the velocity factor of a COAX cable is ~0,77.

But what is the VF of twisted pair? Or other cable types? One of my CD's is 600m --> so the VF should be ~0,27. Is this possible?

Comment: Basically, an ethernet collision domain should be no more than 100 meters. Having a larger collision domain allows for the possibility of late or missed collisions. Your formula holds for older ethernet speeds, but it is different for the faster, more modern speeds. The IEEE 802.3 standards are built with the 100 meter limit in mind. By the way, copper cable is all going to be the same VF.

Comment: This formula is used in 10 MBit/s and 100 MBit/s Ethernet according to Wikipedia and my lecture script. There we got 100 MBit/s and a maximal CD length of 600m. Do I need a different formula for this example?

Comment: No, you merely exceeded the maximum collision domain size, and there can be problems. If you are running things with 10 or 100 Mbps ethernet in half-duplex, then it is probably time to get rid of the hubs and start using switches.

Comment: Oh I forgot to say it's DIX Ethernet.

Comment: You can still use switches or bridges rather than hubs. I'm not sure you can even buy hubs anymore. Ethernet has moved on to switches many years ago, and even cheap switches can perform at wire speed.

Comment: You are absolutely right! But I still need to know the VF of TP Ethernet cable for the calculation. It's just for my understanding...

Comment: As I explained, the VF for copper cables is all the same. The speed of light through copper cable is about two-thirds the speed of light.

Comment: @RonMaupin The VF in copper can vary greatly (.5 to .99). It depends on the permittivity of the dielectric. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_factor#Typical_velocity_factors for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ron Maupin, I now understand what's wrong with my question. 
I misunderstood velocity factor with the nominal velocity of propagation (NVP). 
Which is about 60-100% depends on the cable type. This means, I think so, you can always use a value between this borders of you don't know the cable type.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the questions doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.